# Overriding Custom ArrayAdapter Remove Iterator

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` and I override the add and remove methods.
When I call the remove method, the object being passed is slightly different from the corresponding object in the `ArrayAdapter` that should be removed, some of the fields don't match.
I don't care about these differences and still want what I deem to be a corresponding object to be removed.
How do I do this?
I tried writing an `equals()` method in the class of my object, where I only compared fields of interest, but the function was never called. I also tried finding the index of the object to be removed, by iterating through all the `ArrayAdapter` members inside the remove method and then calling `remove(index)` on the `ArrayList`, this worked, but when the `listView` was being updated, the `getView()` method of the custom ArrayAdapter was called one extra time, not accounting for the object that was removed. 
This was probably because `super.remove(index)` was not called, since `super.remove(object)` is what is expected to be called.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: When you change your adapter, you have to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I did call notifyDataSetChanged() and the list was properly updated, but when I started scrolling through it, I got a null pointer exception in the getView() method which trying to access entry N, even though there were now only N-1 entries.

Comment: Post your getView() method.

Answer (score 1):

I had to override the object's equals method, but when overriding this method, it has to be overridden in the following fashion:

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    CustomClass foo = (CustomClass)obj;

    // now 'this' can be compared to foo, as needed
}
```

I initially wrote an equals method as follows (and it did not get called - I guess I overloaded it, instead of overriding it.

```
public boolean equals (CustomClass obj) {
    // comparing 'this' to obj does not help, since the entire equals method
    // is not called at all
}
```